# Authentication when connecting to multiple proxies

Tags: java, proxy, http-proxy

I can't figure out how to provide the login and password to the **Proxies** **(multiple ones)** when I'm connecting to it. That is to say, `My Main Proxy` can be used by multiple clients and each time it may connect to a different `ProxyX` **in parallel  (in the different threads)**. And there can be multiple connections open at the same time.

```
Client ---> My Main Proxy ---> Proxy1 ----> Internet
```

or

```
Client ---> My Main Proxy ---> Proxy2 ----> Internet
```

or

```
Client ---> My Main Proxy ---> Proxy3 ----> Internet
```

I've found out that a class `Authenticator` can be used. But it, if I understand correctly, it affects all the connections at the same time, so one pair of login-password can interfere with another. Is that so?

The bottom line is that I want to provide login and password to each individual connection from `My Main Proxy` to `ProxyX`.

I'm connecting to `ProxyX` the following way:

```
/*How to provide login and password?*/
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.host", 8080));  
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
```

or

```
/*How to provide login and password?*/
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.host", 80)); 
Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
socket.connect(socketAddress, 1000);
```

Comment: One way to try would be to `Authenticator.setDefault` with custom authenticator before each connection. There must be better way to do this via configurations, though.

Comment: @ringbearer, an if the connections occurred in parallel in the different threads?

Comment: There is no solution that I know of. A quick search unearthed this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171032/how-to-handle-multiple-authenticator